# how do I list all instances tagged with a specific tag (specified under firewall rule's Target tags)

Tags: tags, google-cloud-platform

I have a firewall rule that applies only to instances with a specific tag.
I want to know which are all the instances with this specific tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run (from wherever you have gcloud sdk installed, or Cloud Shell)
`gcloud compute instances list --filter='-tags = your-tag'`

For more information how to format the `--filter=` flag, for example with regular expressions look [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters).

You can also do it in the console, just by typing the tag into the window in Compute Engine which says *Filter by label or name*

Comment: As of Sept 2018, the [syntax](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) is now

`gcloud compute instances list --filter='tags.items = your-tag'`