# Filtering GCP firewall rules by the targetTags field using the Go SDK

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've been trying to list firewall rules with a filter for the targetTags field but I've been unable to get it to successfully return a list.

For reference, what I have is this:

```golang
filter := `targetTags = "web-server"`
req := computepb.ListFirewallsRequest{
    Project: sdk.Project,
    Filter:  &filter,
}
it := sdk.Firewalls.List(ctx, &req)
for { ... }
```

I'm fairly sure that since the targetTags is an array, this is failing as the clause checks for equality. I've tried using `targetTags:(web-server)` but this also fails.

I can always do the filtering in-memory but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible. Anyone k ow how to get this to work?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42554804/609290)

Comment: You can run `gcloud ... --log-http` to see the underlying call that's being made (e.g. by the above). This is documented in [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) for [firewalls.list](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls/list)

Comment: Please reference APIs being used in questions so that it's easier for others to understand. You're undoubtedly using Google's Compute Engine SDK for Go and this provides [Filter](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.65.0/compute/v1#FirewallsListCall.Filter) methods which are more (!?) idiomatic with these libraries (although with the same outcome).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a similar script to test this out, and indeed it doesn’t seem to work regardless of how I send the `TargetTags` filtering string. Looking in the Github repo for the Go library, I found this interesting [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/1019). The root cause appears to be coming from the REST API used internally by the Go library. There’s an open [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188066355) in Google’s issue tracker for this as well, but the resolution does not have an ETA yet.

You would have to create filtering logic for now. Fortunately, the [`GetTargetTags()`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/compute/v1#Firewall.GetTargetTags) method does return the `TargetTags` array for each firewall rule, so you can create a function that filters your rules based on tags.

Comment: @CNevin561 Were you able to check if `GetTargetTags()` helped you create your own filtering?